# How to output ARM V8 assembly from LLVM IR?

Tags: c, assembly, llvm, llvm-ir, armv8

I have this C file:

```
int mult() {
  int a =5;
  int b = 3;
  int c = a * b;
  return c;
}
```

I compile it to LLVM IR like this:

```
$ clang -emit-llvm -S multiply.c -o multiply.ll
```

I then compile it to various x86 assemblies like this:

```
$ llc --filetype asm -o multiply.apple.s --aarch64-neon-syntax=apple multiply.ll
$ llc --filetype asm -o multiply.intel.s --x86-asm-syntax=intel multiply.ll
```

How do I output ARM V8 assembly? Is there any way to convert a C file to output ARM V8 assembly, even without LLVM IR if LLVM IR can't do it? I don't see it in the [llc docs](https://linux.die.net/man/1/llc) for example.

Comment: Have you tried `clang -target arm64 -S multiply.c`?

Comment: Getting tons of errors like `error: unknown type name '__int64_t'` after running that. `clang -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk -target arm64 -S test.c`. Without `-isysroot` I get `fatal error: 'stdlib.h' file not found`.

Comment: Seems like your system libraries do not support compiling for arm64 as is.  Unfortunately I'm not really familiar with compiling on macOS.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`llc -march=aarch64 multiply.ll -o multiply.s` will do it.

However, you shouldn't actually do that because the translation from C to LLVM IR is target-dependent. Simple things will work and complex programs will break in seemingly impossible ways.

Instead, go directly from C to your target with `clang -target arm64`. As your programs get more complicated, such as using system headers, you'll need to have an SDK matching the target platform installed. Even `#include <stdlib.h>` is very different on two platforms.